# My lambda and EC2 are in a VPC and I cant putRecords to kinesis from lambda but I can from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis

I have a setup in aws, EC2 -> kinesis_x -> lambda -> kinesis_x
(kinesis_x: to illustrate that this is that same kinesis stream)
EC2 and lambda are in the same VPC.
I can publish from lambda to kinesis_x.

I've configured a VPC endpoint, that did the trick but it disabled the EC2 from publishing to kinesis.
Same security groups for EC2 and lambda.

After enabling the endpoint, this is the timeout exception from the java application in my EC2:

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to kinesis.us-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 [kinesis.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/10.1.1.180, kinesis.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/10.1.2.157] failed: connect timed out
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:150)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)

I want to be able to publish to the same kinesis stream from EC2 and Lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!
We attached our security group to the Endpoint and that did the trick!
This sg is the same as our EC2 and Lambda function has.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check, looking at the error the client cannot connect so:

- Is the VPC public/private?
- Are you using multiple subnets?
- If private does it have an internet gateway?
- What routes are setup?

All of the basic IP networking rules apply with a VPC.

Also telnet is your friend. A good trick is to SSH/SSM into the EC2 instance and try to connect using telnet eg

```
telnet ip port
```

This lets you isolate network connectivity from application-level issues.

Comment: Thank you fro the quick reply!

Private VPC.
Yes, multiple subnets. 
Yes it does, I can access the internet from my VPC.
I have 2 routs: local  and igw for full access.

After enabling VPC endpoint I couldn't telnet the kinesis IP.
The application can definitely publish to kinesis, without the endpoint, so it is not application level error.